# jquery sometimes work sometimes not

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I try to modift the column of an external list in sharepoint.

`alert(1)` `alert(2)` works. But `alert(3)` doesn't work always. What is the problem? Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    alert(1); 
    $().ready(function() { 
          alert(2);     
          $('table[summary="CalisanBilgi"] ').each(function() {
              alert(3);         
              $('td:last-child', $(this)).html('<img src="http://ahapp/img/image.aspx?s="'+$('td:last-child', $(this)).html() +'" />')  
          });
    }); 

    </script>
```

**EDITED:**

It is the code of the list where I can see the html with Web Dev Tools from browser.
I try to modify the last column named ID to display the image of the person.

```
<table  summary="CalisanBilgi" ....>
<tbody>
<tr class=" ms-itmHoverEnabled ms-itmhover">
<td class="ms-cellStyleNonEditable ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-imgFirstCell">
ID
</td>
<td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">
NAME
</td>
<td class="ms-vb-lastCell ms-cellstyle ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell">
ID
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**ANSWER:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('table[summary="CalisanBilgi"] tr').find('.ms-vb-lastCell').each(function(){

           $(this).html('<img src="http://ahapp/img/image.aspx?s=' + $(this).html() + '"/>') ;       
       });  

});
```

Comment: do you get any error message ?

Comment: No, I didn't.Is it possible to put an error log for jquery?

Comment: there is a js console in most modern browsers. But maybe you won't get any error in it, cause from where I see it your code looks ok. We'll need more explanation (what do you mean by "doesn't work") and more code to help you

Comment: I add some information to the question.

Comment: That helps. Now what is the problem exactly ? Is it that when you have multiple rows, it only works with the last one ?

Comment: Yes I have 300 rows. But I can't change the last td. At the first time when I edit the code, It works. but after it doesn't work. Is it true that I use ".each"? I'm new at jquery. So the code can be wrong.

Comment: cfr my answer... please accept it if this is what you needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do what you want :

```
   $(document).ready(function() 
   { 
       $('table[summary="CalisanBilgi"] tr td:last-child').each(function()
       {
           $(this).html('<img src="http://ahapp/img/image.aspx?s=' + $(this).html() + '"/>') ;       
       });
   });
```

cfr [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQGYW/1/)

Some words of explanation :

1)selector `table[summary="CalisanBilgi"] tr td:last-child` selects an array of the lasts `td` of each `tr` in table with summary `'table[summary="CalisanBilgi"] tr td:last-child'`

2) Within the `each()` function, each one of these td is identified by `$(this)`

3) I just take the html content of this `td` , containing the id of the user, and use it to generate the `img` tag which finally replaces the original content.

I would sugest though that you generate this content through sharepoint (server) code, which would be much cleaner...

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot the semi-colon

here

`$('td:last-child', $(this)).html('<img src="http://ahapp/img/image.aspx?s="'+$('td:last-child', $(this)).html() +'" />')`**;**

Comment: JavaScript has automatic semicolon insertion. While semicolons are considered by many "best practice", this is not a problem with OP's code.